What is the difference between a phrasal verb, a prepositional verb and a phrasal prepositional verb?
My pupils find it hard to find out if a verb is a phrasal verb, a prepositional verb or a phrasal prepositional verb.

There is a lack of consensus among grammarians on how to name and classify the various multi-word verbs. For example, the authoritative Cambridge Grammar of the English Language has a single short paragraph on phrasal verbs which concludes "It is for this reason that we do not use the term phrasal verb in this grammar. " Is your aim for the pupils to equip them with some of the classification criteria that have been used?

The question will have greater success if you give an example where your students get confused e.g. "I was talked into giving a speech" or something similar.

Please give a sentence for each of your categories.

@Greybeard Don't you think that she would not have asked her question in the first place if she were able to do that?

@Tchrst. I am assuming that the OP herself has done some research and seen examples of verbs that appear (or are said to) to fall into the categories of phrasal, prepositional, and phrasal prepositional verbs but cannot fully distinguish them and or see the pattern.

This has been addressed on ELU several times. The classification of such multi-word verbs (MWVs) into the three distinct classes your analysis (ESL bias?) posits is rejected by a good many grammarians. I can't find the excellent overview of types there is in one thread; Claridge's 'Multi-word verbs in early modern English' (it also addresses modern English very well) is, I'd say, essential reading on MWVs. Is 'put together' a phrasal verb? illustrates the difficulty in deciding on MWV vs V + Adv 0r Prep.

Related questions, including probable duplicates: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8. This list is not meant to be exhaustive; others exist.

Constituency tests needed to differentiate between 'phrasal verbs' and {verb + prep} looks at the basics involved in trying to identify exactly what a MWV is. Classification into transitive/intransitive, separable (optionally or obligatorily) with transitive examples, degree of opaqueness, two-part or three-part must come later.

Another thread worth reading is: Is the second word in {strings} like 'throw out' and-'write down' a preposition or adverb {or particle}? (J Lawler's balanced answer).

@EdwinAshworth What's unclear about this? Do you know the difference between a phrasal verb, a prepositional verb and a phrasal prepositional verb?

Comparative analysis with other Germanic languages can be helpful. Even Latin-derived verbs (e.g. "provide")  consist of a preposition united with a verb stem.  In Germanic languages you have "spooky action at a distance" between those two elements.  "I have to provide for my family. I have to look out for my family".

@Laurel By actually choosing to use that terminology, you're assuming that such an analysis is the only or only acceptable one. If you read John Lawler's discussion of this in various threads, you'll see that different grammarians use the tern 'phrasal verb' in different and conflicting ways, and CGEL for instance does not accept the term 'phrasal verb' at all. I think it's unhelpful because there is no consensus on the definition.  Perhaps an ELL answer might be framed around this simplistic analysis, but Claridge spends many pages discussing terminology & approaches by respected grammarians.

The factors involved are essentially transitivity, particle shift (mandatory, optional, or disallowed), one or two particles/adverbs/prepositions, literal vs metaphorical semantics, and at heart the cohesiveness of the verb-particle (some even reject that term) string. I could ask Have you read Claridge on the different terminologies and analyses of multi-word verbs? which I see as a more scholarly take on the whole topic.

//// See also prepositional verb structure: << {rely on} {John} or {rely} {on John}? >>, John Lawler's answer stating that the answer is indeterminate (and of little value anyway).

<< There are three types of multi-word verbs: phrasal verbs, prepositional verbs and phrasal-prepositional verbs. Sometimes, the name ‘phrasal verb’ is used to refer to all three types. >>  [Cambridge Dictionary] //// This definition of MWVs ignores unusual verb-verb constructions (make do, let go ...) and fixed intransitive or transitivised verbo-nominal constructions (break camp, take cover; take note of, take pride in ...) that some analysts include as MWVs (again, see Claridge).
